# Calling pdflatex inside C code

Tags: pdftex, compiling

I am writing C code that writes a `LaTeX` file for me.  I then attempt to compile the file using `pdflatex` in a `non-interactive` mode (as in I'm automating some process and don't want to wait for user input on fatal error).  The LaTeX file is output at `./data/output_date.tex` and I attempt to compile it using the command

```
system("./pdflatex --interaction=nonstopmode --output-directory=data ./data/output_date.tex");
```

However, I get the error message:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
entering extended mode
(./data/output_date.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/pbox/pbox.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))
(data/output_2013_date.aux))
! Emergency stop.
<*> ./data/output_date.tex

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on data/output_date.log.
```

I can't seem to decipher why exactly I'm getting an emergency stop, especially because when I run the same exact command from the terminal (from the same folder as the `C` executable), the `LaTeX` compiles fine to `pdf`.

Is there something special I have to do because I'm calling the compiler as a command from `C` code?

EDIT: Here is the text of the corresponding `.log` file.  The only thing it seems to say is that `no legal \end found`, which confuses me because I checked the source file to make sure my `\begin` and `\end` match up.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2013.5.23)  15 JUL 2013 09:50
entering extended mode
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./data/output_date.tex
(./data/output_date.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/pbox/pbox.sty
Package: pbox 2003/04/06 v1.0 Dynamic parboxes

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count87
\calc@Bcount=\count88
\calc@Adimen=\dimen103
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen104
\calc@Askip=\skip43
\calc@Bskip=\skip44
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 76.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 77.
\calc@Ccount=\count89
\calc@Cskip=\skip45
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
\pb@xlen=\skip46
)
(data/output_date.aux)
\openout1 = `output_date.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 15.
)
! Emergency stop.
<*> ./data/output_date.tex

*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 375 strings out of 495061
 4422 string characters out of 1182621
 56939 words of memory out of 3000000
 3619 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+50000
 6675 words of font info for 24 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 28 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,14n,19p,304b,189s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Can you show the `data/output_date.log` after running `C` code?

Comment: Added above as an edit.  Like I say there, I'm confused because I double checked the source and the \begin and \end commands match up as they should, yet I'm still getting an error about a missing \end (I think?).

Comment: Either `\end{document}` is missing or there is a syntax error in your file. You can add `\typeout{***************}` or move `\end{document}` to earlier locations to investigate the more exact location of the problem.

Comment: It is rather strange that it should work from the command line but not from a C program. I would try it with a fixed and minimal example tex-document. If that still fails something else is wrong, maybe an open file reference?

Comment: Try with `sample2e.tex` (which is in `texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/sample2e.tex` and which pdflatex should find automagically). If _that_ works, the problem is in your file.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a non problem.

Comment: Not migrated, because it's solved and a simple issue. so closing is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to close the file for writing (in the C code) before I attempt to compile it with the `pdflatex` command. I had inadvertently added it after the `fclose` command .

My guess is my ordering either hadn't flushed the buffer one last time (which would have included the `\end{document}`) before attempting to compile or the file being in use affected the pdflatex somehow.